# JNA char** argument

Tags: java, jna

I need to call a DLL function from java with a string array argument. The argument value has to be the same arguments passed to the java program from command line (main method argument). The function has following signature:

```
int calledFunction(char **args);
```

The main method argument is type is `String[]` and according to the [JNA documentation](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.0/javadoc/overview-summary.html), `String[]` should be directly equivalent to `char **`.

But when I pass the argument from command line directly to the DLL, the program crashes or the DLL doesn't interpret the values correctly (the values don't make sense).

Any ideas?

JNA interface definition:

```
public interface TestDll extends Library {

    int calledFunction(String[] param);

}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestDll testDll = Native.loadLibrary("test_dll", TestDll.class);
    testDll.calledFunction(args);
}
```

Comment: have you tried `str.toCharArray()`?

Comment: And how exactly do you know the number of strings in the array? (argc)

Comment: @Tschallacka what exactly do you mean? Can you provide a code example?

Comment: @manuell it's supposed to be a null-terminated array.... maybe that's the problem ... don't know if JNA terminates the array with null by default or not... but I also tried appending null as the last element of the java string array and that didn't work.

Comment: not null, but `"\0"` as last character. You didn't give a code example of how you call your code, so I have no idea how you implemented it/call it.

Comment: @Jardo `char** args` is an array of pointers. You definitely needs to show your `C` code!

Comment: @manuell I don't have the code, its a third-party library.

Comment: @Jarno A third-party library which doesn't document how the function can know the number of pointers?

Comment: The documentation says its a "null-terminated array". So i figure the last value is supposed to be null.

Comment: @Jarno, OK, an array of pointers terminated by a `nullptr` as last member of the array is fine. Now, you must show the Java code...

Comment: I'll add the code to the question. Btw, when called from c++ you are supposed to pass the second argument from main method (argv) directly to the DLL method. I tried to write a small c++ program with this approach and it works.

Comment: @Jardo o_O Thank you very much, I learned something today! `the C Standard actually guarantees that argv[argc] will be NULL`. You problem is the Java side constructing an array of pointer with the last element set to a null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new array, bigger (by 2) than `args`

```
String[] new_str_array = new String[ args.length + 2 ] // +1 for program name, +1 for null
```

- A regular C function managing the char **args of a main function, expect the first string to be the program name.
- The array of pointer must be terminated by an extra null pointer

Then, you you should put the program name at the beginning

```
new_str_array[ 0 ] = "MyProgramExecutableName";
```

Then, copy the args passed to the Java program

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
   new_str_array[ 1+i ] = args[ i ];
}
```

Then call the C function with `new_str_array`, the last `string` (at index `args.length + 1`) should have been correctly set to `null` (by the `new` instruction)

Comment: This was exactly the problem! The dll expected the first parameter to be the program name and java simply doesn't put it there. Thanks for the response. Anyway, the trailing null doesn't have to be there. JNA takes care of it.